# programmatic access to docker volumes from host

Tags: docker

I am using the docker HTTP API described [here](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/api/docker_remote_api/).

Suppose I get a volume ID using the `GET /volumes` API endpoint. Is it possible for me to inspect the contents of this volume (list files, read files)?

I understand that I could create a container that mounts this volume and then use the `/containers/(id)/archive` endpoint to download files from it, but this seems like a rather expensive operation when all I wish to do is inspect the contents of a single file on the volume.

Answer (score 1):

I think the right thing is too execute the scripts you want to execute in a container with the volumes mounted, but you can just list the files and folders in the volume folder here : `/var/lib/docker/volumes/`.

This path is gonna change if you tweak a bit docker, but your volumes are always stored somewhere, just go inside the folder corresponding at your volume ID.

See ya !

Comment: It's worth noting that if you are using an abstraction layer such as docker-machine, Docker for Mac, Docker for Windows, that this `/var/lib` directory may be inside a VM on your system, not on the main system itself.